# extract string from multiple columns in new column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I want to find a word in different columns and mutate it in a new column.

"data" is an example and "goal" is what I want. I tried a lot but I didn't get is work.

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(stringr)

 data <- tibble(
    component1 = c(NA, NA, "Word", NA, NA, "Word"),
    component2 = c(NA, "Word", "different_word", NA, NA, "not_this")
    )

 goal <- tibble(
    component1 = c(NA, NA, "Word", NA, NA, "Word"),
    component2 = c(NA, "Word", "different_word", NA, NA, "not_this"),
    component = c(NA, "Word", "Word", NA, NA, "Word")
    )


not_working <- data %>%
     mutate(component = across(starts_with("component"), ~ str_extract(.x, "Word")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `if_any` and `str_detect`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  mutate(component = ifelse(if_any(starts_with("component"), str_detect, "Word"), "Word", NA))
```

output

```r
  component1 component2     component
  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>    
1 NA         NA             NA       
2 NA         Word           Word     
3 Word       different_word Word     
4 NA         NA             NA       
5 NA         NA             NA       
6 Word       not_this       Word
```

---

If you wanna stick to `str_extract`, this would be the way to go:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("component"), str_extract, "Word", 
         .names = "{.col}_extract")) %>% 
  mutate(component = coalesce(component1_extract, component2_extract),
         .keep = "unused")
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  component1     component2     component
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>    
1 NA             NA             NA       
2 NA             Word           Word     
3 Word           different_word Word     
4 NA             NA             NA       
5 NA             NA             NA       
6 different_word Word           Word
```

Answer (score 7):

For your provided data structure we could use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(component = coalesce(component1, component2))
```

```
component1 component2     component
  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>    
1 NA         NA             NA       
2 NA         Word           Word     
3 Word       different_word Word     
4 NA         NA             NA       
5 NA         NA             NA       
6 Word       not_this       Word
```

Comment: this is beautiful!

Comment: This does not work in the case where component1 is "different_word" and component2 is "Word". Although very succinct, I'm not sure this answer would work in every case.

Comment: That is true, therefore my reminder in my answer "for this data structure".

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I thought about this but I needed a solution with if_any or across because I import data and the number of columns with "Word" differs. Only the name of the column always starts with "components"